# Issue in running review board on apache2

Tags: python, ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, review-board

I am setting up **review board** on a ubuntu machine. I am having another service running on port 80 so i have changed the port no **8082**.
I have followed  the setup given in the below link
https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/2.0/admin/installation/creating-sites

I have made the default site as the site what i have created.
I executed the following command

```
 **sudo service apache2 restart**

 Restarting web server apache2                                         [ OK ]
```

But the server is not up i am getting Bad request error 400 error.

### /etc/apache2/ports.conf Listen 8082

*In the logs 
 caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Mar 26 12:42:18.528501 2015] [:notice] [pid 9600:tid 140110870382464] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 6 max processes and 25 max threads.
[Thu Mar 26 12:42:18.528632 2015] [:notice] [pid 9600:tid 140110870382464] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
[Thu Mar 26 12:42:18.557103 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 9600:tid 140110870382464] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Mar 26 12:42:18.557154 2015] [core:notice] [pid 9600:tid 140110870382464] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'*